# getPreventDefault() - Is it possible to overwrite, replace or something like that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, deprecated, preventdefault

I have an application that is so modular and use so much of getPreventDefault(), that would take me days to change it to defaultPrevented in all files.

I'm in Windows 7, so some kind of recursive script is too unsafe to that project.

I tried to make getPreventDefault() use defaultPrevented, something like:

```
function getPreventDefault(e) {
        return defaultPrevented(e);
}
```

I tried a lot of others ways, but nothing...

Is it possible to do it? My idea for that is keep using getPreventDefault() without warning, until I finish to fix some issues, and then back to change it.

*Simple code to test the remove of warning...*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <script>
                        function OnBodyClick (event) {
                                if (event.getPreventDefault) {  // Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
                                        if (event.getPreventDefault ()) {
                                                console.log ("The default action is canceled.");
                                        } else {
                                                console.log ("The default action is not canceled.");
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                </script>
        </head>
        <body onclick="OnBodyClick(event)">
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why can't you do a file search and replace?

Comment: It will not be safe, once it is a Windows script, not POSIX, that another person should run, since  I have access only for "my part" of the page, this is a multi country web system, my friends of the Old Continent don't have time to fix things like that, so I first will remove this warings (something like 200 or more), after that I will help they to fix it.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `getPreventDefault(event)` instead of `event.getPreventDefault` based on your getPreventDefault function?

Comment: Now everyone needs to use defaultPrevented, since getPreventDefault is deprecated and show warnings, that's why I need to somehow make getPreventDefault call defaultPrevented instead of the build in function... Because of the number of warings (more than 1000), we start to update de application to remove this warnings before deprecated functions become removed functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sould be fine with using javascript prototype override

```
Object.prototype.getPreventDefault = function (e) {       
    return e.defaultPrevented;
}
```

If you would like to overwrite a jQuery function, you can use this code after you loaded jQuery

```
(function ($) {    
    $.fn.getPreventDefault = function(e) {
        return e.defaultPrevented;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I tried both and FF (probably others) is still showing the warnings messages, I posted an update with a simple code that shows the warnings.

Comment: Seems like FF is always showing the warning messages and does not allow to overwrite the getPreventDefault function.
Therefor I would strongly recommend you to update your code and replace every getPreventDefault, it is a lot of work.. but you will be faster by doing it now instead of searching for a hotfix and doing it afterwards. Regards

Answer (score 0):

[defaultPrevented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented) is a **property** of `Event`, so you have to write your function like this:

```js
function getPreventDefault(e) {
    return e.defaultPrevented;
}
```

Comment: I tried and FF (probably others) is still showing the warnings messages, I posted an update with a simple code that shows the warnings.